Density distribution in flexible material when squeezed
A full rubber ball, a foam mattress: when we push against them a bit locally, the overall form stays the same, except around where we push, but the volume is reduced, so there must be density variations now in the material - I assume. (Of course the density must be averaged over a few foam bubbles.)
Is there some theory how the density varies around the pushed location? Like for a canonical material it goes, say, with 1/r where r is the distance from where we push (complete guess)?

It depends in great part on the exact geometry you’re using, how you’re pushing, what shape in which pressure is applied, material properties, etc… it would be very useful to either specify a material with known properties and/or a much simpler case (like a ball being compressed).

Pity, I was afraid this might be the outcome, which is why I mentioned "canonical material" and hoping we have a situation similar to Navier-Stokes for "viscous material", where viscous material is also very general.

"Canonical material" is up to debate, but one of the simplest model is that of an elastic, homogeneous, isotropic material. Given the displacement field $u$, the stress tensor is given by:
$$
\sigma = 2\mu\epsilon+\lambda\text{Tr}(\epsilon)I \\
\epsilon = \frac{\nabla\otimes u+\nabla\otimes u^T}2
$$
with $\epsilon$ the strain tensor and $\lambda,\mu$ the Lamé parameters. Static equilibrium is given by:
$$
\nabla\cdot\sigma+f=0 \\
\mu\Delta u+(\mu+\lambda)\nabla(\nabla\cdot u)+f = 0
$$
with $f$ external volumic force.
While Lamé coefficients are mathematically more natural, physically it may be more familiar to use instead Young's modulus $E$ and Poisson's ratio $\nu$:
$$
\lambda = \frac{E\nu}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)} \quad \mu = \frac{E}{2(1+\nu)}
$$
In many physical applications, your medium is incompressible ($\nu=1/2$). In this case, $\lambda=+\infty$, and the equations are rather:
$$
\mu\Delta u-\nabla p+f = 0
$$
with $p$ internal pressure to impose the incompressibility condition:
$$
\nabla\cdot u=0
$$
While it is more rare physically, you can also have the "shearless" (unshearable?) limit ($\nu=-1$) where $\lambda,\mu=+\infty$ but you still have finite bulk modulus $K=E/9=\lambda+2\mu/3$:
$$
\nabla\times v+K\nabla(\nabla\cdot u) +f=0
$$
with $v$ imposes the no shear condition:
$$
\epsilon=\frac{\nabla\cdot u}3I
$$
(Physically, it may be more transparent to replace $\nabla\times v=\nabla\cdot\sigma_0$ with $\sigma_0$ an internal traceless, symmetric stress tensor to impose the no shear condition, but mathematically it is more cumbersome)
You can therefore model the local "push" by a localised $f$, i.e. a Dirac delta $f=F\delta$. It turns out that it is simpler to solve what is happening when applying the force within the bulk of the material. In this case, $u$ is the Green's function. You can compute it analytically and it does decay as $r^{-1}$ like the Coulomb potential (which is not surprising as the equations are essentially the same). Check out for example Landau-Lifschitz' Theory of Elasticity (solved problem at the end of §8, 2nd ed.).
If you really want to model the imprint the applying a force at the surface, you will need to add boundary conditions (typically stress free in your case) and it will not have a simple analytical solution. You can expect that it will also decay as $r^{-1}$ by simple scaling arguments. In the case of a weak applied force, you can linearise the boundary condition and find a simple analytic solution. Detailed calculations of this simplied setting can be found in Landau-Lifschitz' Theory of Elasticity (§8, 2nd ed.).

Your material choices (rubber and foam) notably correspond to Poisson ratio idealizations of $\frac{1}{2}$ and 0, respectively.
Materials with a Poisson ratio of $\frac{1}{2}$ are condensed and continuous but relatively compliant; that is, they have a very low shear modulus $G$ relative to their bulk modulus $K$. (The Poisson ratio—at least under linear elasticity—is taken as $\nu=\frac{3K-2G}{2(3K+G)}$; confirm that $G\ll K$ implies $\nu\approx\frac{1}{2}$.) An interesting consequence is that the volume is essentially conserved and the density essentially constant even for large shear deformations. The physical interpretation is that the polymer chains of a rubber elastomer can easily uncoil, unkink, and stretch to rearrange but that they are not easily compressed. So to first order, the answer to your first question is that the density in the rubber ball is essentially unaltered.
The situation for foam is different. There's plenty of room for the cell walls of deformed foam to collapse into the open cells, so Poisson effects (i.e., lateral expansion/contraction upon longitudinal loading) are nearly absent. (Hooke noticed this effect with cork and indeed named cells, including porous-material cells and biological cells, after monks' quarters.) Here, we can take the density as $\rho=\rho_0/(1+\varepsilon_{11}+\varepsilon_{22}+\varepsilon_{33})$, where $\varepsilon_{11}$, $\varepsilon_{22}$, and $\varepsilon_{33}$ are the normal strains. Given a surface poke, what are these strains? This is the so-called Boussinesq problem; if linear elasticity is assumed, the displacement field can be used to calculate the normal strains and then the density variation.
